# "container is undefined" jQuery farbtastic issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, farbtastic

I am using  farbtastic Editor for changing inline text,here is the [link](https://github.com/mquan/freshereditor)

Every thing is working fine independently ,But when I try to integrate it with my application.It throws error saying "container is undefined
jQuery.farbtastic",I have checked all the file path and all are correct.Is anyone is familiar with this error.I just found same issue posted by a user here is the [link](http://papermashup.com/jquery-farbtastic-colour-picker/)

Here is the code that throwing error

```
    jQuery.farbtastic = function (container, callback) {
  var container = $(container).get(0);
  return container.farbtastic || (container.farbtastic = new jQuery._farbtastic(container, callback));
}
```

Comment: `$( document ).ready()` ?

Comment: I just sent a single function of  "farbtasic.js" where I am getting error. You can check the same file from above link(first one).On line 27

Comment: are u sure if the container element is present in the DOM when you call farbtastic ? if yes, you can try calling it in document ready as in the previous comment from paul.

Comment: I think you guys are right.